# Resources for learning Automated Testing in C# and WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, mvvm

I've been tasked with doing research into unit testing for both the model and model-view sections of the MVVM model. I am having problems finding resources for this to read up on. The emphasis of this research is Automated testing, checking to see if existing code still works and edge cases.

Any help would be greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Unless I deeply misunderstand MVVM and I suspect not since we've been doing variants on it for 4 years)

These are both non UI centric types and thus testing them is, in main simple, just using standard unit test tools (we use MSTest, but you can use any of the other e.g. NUnit, XUnit etc..)

Comment: I think I was overcomplicating things when I asked this, thank you for your straightfoward answer